# Cannot install Atom on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: mate, atom

I have Mate 1.10.2 and have been trying to install Atom text editor (use it on my windows 10) but can't get it to install. I get this message.

```
ryan@fr00t:~$ sudo dpkg -i atom-amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive atom-amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 atom-amd64.deb
ryan@fr00t:~$ sudo dpkg -i atom-amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive atom-amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 atom-amd64.deb
```

Comment: Try installing the deb with GDEBI instead - `sudo apt install gdebi-core`, `sudo gdebi <package>.deb`, where <package> refers to the name of the DEB file.

Answer (score 2):

With a PPA for the Atom editor:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/atom
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install atom
```

---

Or with my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/630530/367165).