# Automation of installing programs from source

Tags: package-management, software-installation, updates, compiling, packaging

I occasionally face a problem when using programs for which developers don't publish deb packages and only provide source. Sometimes I find a PPA providing the package but sometimes I don't or sometimes I don't trust the third party's version of the package because the program is rather sensitive from the security point of view (e.g. a password manager).

I can install from the source but this is ok to do once, not to do it on regular basis so as to install program's updates. Therefore, I'm thinking...

**Is there a tool which would automate installation from the sources?**

1. **Check for updated source.** (e.g. in a Git repo)
2. **Download the code.**
3. **Compile it in the background.**
4. **Offer installation the similar way the Ubuntu's update manager would?**

I guess I could probably put the process together using Jenkins and some custom coding but it's possibly quite a bit of work and I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

PS: Answers like the one for [Atom editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589469/how-to-automatically-update-atom-editor) lack some expected features when having to deal with the installation of multiple programs this way:

- **management of the configuration** for each of them
- **download from different sources** (tar archive, Git repo, etc.)
- **checking** the source on daily basis and **tracking** whether there is a need to proceed with the update
- **resolving dependencies**
- check that the **compilation** succeeded
- **offer to install the package** instead of installing it automatically

In other words, I'm looking for something that would put user-friendliness into the process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically update Atom editor?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/589469/how-to-automatically-update-atom-editor)

Comment: @A.B. I have added extra explanation on the features expected and why I don't think it's duplicate of the other question you  brought up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Linuxbrew

> [Linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/) is a fork of Homebrew, the macOS package manager, for
>   Linux.

It is exactly what you are looking for.

You may check [Homebrew page](https://brew.sh/) to understand *What Does Homebrew/Linuxbrew Do?*

Comment: This indeed looks like something I had in mind. I'll play with it in the upcoming days and would eventually mark your answer as the solution.